# How do I configure MySQL to store specific entire InnoDB tables on a different drive in Windows ( Server )?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, partitioning

After skimming the MySQL ( 5.5 ) docs on Partitioning, that seems to deal with breaking parts of the same table off onto other drives. I'm struggling to find information on how I pinpoint an incessantly used table in an application and throw it onto its own drive.

Comment: Nevermind, it's trivial. You just define an absolute path in the create table statement. Yay for MySQL.